# Javascript Format returns day of 0

Tags: javascript, date, format

Javascript rookie here:

```
function calcExpiration(){
    var getState = jQuery( "#state" ).text();
    var getcalldate = jQuery( "#date" ).text();
    var date = new Date( getcalldate  );
    if (getState == "KY" || getState == "IN"){
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
    }
    if (getState == "WV" || getState == "OH"){
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    }
    var expmonth = date.getMonth()+1;
    var expdate = date.getDay();
    var expyear = date.getFullYear();
    jQuery( "#expiration" ).html( expmonth + "/" + expdate + "/" + expyear);
}
calcExpiration();
```

When getcalldate = 01/02/2015

Returns 2/0/2015

What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't use the Date constructor to parse strings, e.g. in `var date = new Date( getcalldate )`. It's inconsistent and unreliable across browsers. Much better tell users the format you require and parse it yourself (see [*javascript Date.parse*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse/2587398#2587398)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly , you should call `getDate()` to return the day of the month, and not `getDay()` which will return `0` because your date (February 1st 2015) is `Sunday` and the function returns Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 etc.

Comment: You nailed it. I was using the wrong date function.